# Run windows command from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to run the following command from eclipse..and print that result on eclipse console(Im comparing 2 files)

"fc /c/1 /n file1path file2path". 
Here is my code

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c fc /c/1 /n file1path file2path");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line =new String(); 

                try {
                    line = input.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    while (line  != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = input.readLine();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        p.waitFor();
```

But its not printing anything..What is wrong with the code??

Comment: `/c/1`is an invalid parameter, `/1`does not exist. Please use `fc /?` on your console to list all available parameters.

Comment: additionally : you are not writing to the console at all. You will need to debug that app and look at the contents of `line` if you want to see it - or simply print `line`to `System.out`

Comment: Thanx, input.readLine() returns null..but it works fine on the console

Comment: Thanx, its working now, the problem was, in the file path, there was space in one of the folder names..

Comment: i removed the spaces and its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is fine and works for me. The problem is in your command. Change your command and remove the `cmd` and extra `/c` flag. Also remove the invalid flag `/c/1`. Your final command should look like :-

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("fc /c /n file1path file2path");
```

Comment: Thanx..but, input.readLine() returns null for me..but it works fine on the command prompt

Comment: and p.getInputStream() ISNOT NULL

Comment: Thanx, its working now, the problem was, in the file path, there was space in one of the folder names..i removed the spaces and its working now

Comment: Yes like i said the code was not the problem, the command was. Please mark as answer if proved useful :)